# Oracle Driver can't be found in jar on other machines

Tags: java, oracle, jar

I'm attempting to export a jar file containing the ojdbc14.jar, to allow execution outside of my machine. I can do so successfully with the current export of my jar, but only on my computer, when others try it fails with the error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` when it attempts to call `Class.forName`

I have seen many similar questions on SO concerning this, but none of the questions seem to have the exact problem, and the solutions aren't working either.

**Class:**

```
InputStream inputStream = JdbcConnection.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("properties/jdbc.properties");

    try {

        PROPERTIES.load(inputStream); //Load the jdbc properties


        //System.out.println(properties.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));  <-- this prints out the correct output`
        Class.forName(PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")).newInstance(); //Load the oracle driver
```

**Manifest:** (my ojdbc14.jar is located in lib, but the jar will only work on my local machine if just "ojdbc14.jar" is included, the other jars don't have an issue with the path provided, not sure if that is important)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: JdbcConnection
Class-Path:  lib/ojdbc14.jar ojdbc14.jar extrsrcs/kxml2-2.3.0.jar extrsrcs/xstream-1.4.2.jar src/properties/jdbc.properties
```

**UPDATE:**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998264/command-line-parameters-with-jarsplice) better explains how I resolved my issue, as it was related to Jar-within-Jars, executable jars, and etc.

Comment: Java can't load classes from a jar inside a jar. It's that simple. jars must not be put inside other jar files.

Comment: So that's it? There's no workaround for this?

Comment: There are workarounds, and they are all ugly. Why don't you simply zip the whole directory structure, containing a simple .bat/.sh file that you just have to double-click? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html for how to work with jar files and manifest.

Comment: Well the initial requirement was for an executable jar. Could you please link solutions to either of those(if you have them)? Least ugly, preferably.

Comment: You may avoid the .bat file if the jar is executable, but you'll need to put other jar files outside the main jar file, not inside. I already linked to the tutorial in my previous comment.

Comment: I just found something called JarSplice, it seems like it would be an appropriate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think you could include other jars within a jar (that is what your trying to do isn't it?)
I suspect it's working on your machine because ojdbc14.jar is on your classpath somewhere (ie. as the standalone file, rather than included in your jar)

Hope this helps
Nathan

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do. But if I set the classpath in the Manifest, and the driver is in the jar, why wouldn't it still work?