# command line parameters with JarSplice?

Tags: java, jar

[JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) allows the aggregation of jar files and other dependencies and libraries to be combined into one executable jar file.

However, my executable jar requires two command line arguments, which don't seem to be passed at all when I call the JarSplice jar.

I didn't see anything on the site of how to do it, or if it's even possible. Curious if anyone had run into this issue, or found a possible solution.

**Update**

I should have also added that my main class is specified in the JarSplice setup, and is called successfully. However, if I call java -jar myjar.jar param1 param2, and then try and print param1 and param2, they are null.

Comment: Doesn't this _fat jar_ get executed as a normal JAR with `java -jar myfat.jar [my app options...]`?

Comment: Yes, but the params are not going through to the main correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm affraid, this tool has some serious flaws.

Instead of just setting your *Main-Class* in the *fat.jar* `MANIFEST.MF`, it sets it's own `org.ninjacave.jarsplice.core.JarSpliceLauncher` as a *Main-Class*.

Then, when you start your *fat.jar* (using `java -jar fat.jar`) this `JarSpliceLauncher` class starts a **new process** using a `ProcesBuilder` and does not pass any extra parameters to it.

For me, its just a bug / bad design in the [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice).

Now, the workaround for this is to pass your actual *Main-Class* to `java` executable like this:

```
java -cp fat.jar org.myawesomeapp.MyAwesomeClass [params....]
```

Also, there are other (*better*) options:

1. Read about [Maven Assembly Plugin, and it's `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies).
2. In Eclipse, you can use *Export* => *Runnable JAR* => Select *Extract required libraries into generated JAR*.

Comment: Ouch!  That's a major bungle, IMO.

Comment: @StephenC I agree completely. npe, How did you know that JarSplice would even accept the main class? I looked for documentation everywhere and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @JWiley I ran it and created a _fat.jar_. It allows inserting main-class in the GUI, and then puts it inside a `MANIFEST.MF` but in the field called `Launcher-Main-Class`. Then I decompiled the `JarSpliceLauncher` and looked inside. Now this is **fun**!. It reopens the jar internally (using `getProtectionDomain()` hack), parses the `MANIFEST.MF` and gets the _real_ main-class. Then executes the jar in another process using this real main-class. Oh my....

Comment: I'm confused as to how that's different than adding the main class in the JarSplice GUI option, which I saw was being added in the 'MANIFEST.MF' already. Also, I tried the eclipse runnable jar, but I had issues there with having jars within jars, which is why I came to JarSplice. If you have any addition info, that'd be great, but thanks for the excellent response!

Comment: My mistake, sorry, the option on Eclipse should be "_Extract required libraries into generated JAR_". That repackages all libraries into your JAR along with your code. I've edited the answer. And one more thing - if you are using any commercial, closed-source libraries, check if their license allows for repackaging. It's not obvious.